# Invalid identifier in pivot query snowflake

Tags: pivot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have data in following format as the output; columns are date, cohort name, and rate.please ignore the remaining columns;

```
Date         Group_nm        Rate
2019-10-08      A            0.43
2019-10-09      A            0.46
2019-10-08      B             1.5
2019-10-09      B              2
```

The goal is to get it pivoted in following format;

```
Group_nm   2019-10-08   2019-10-09   
  A          0.43          0.46
  B           1.5            2
```

Here is my attempt;

```
SELECT * FROM

(SELECT 
date, group_nm, rate
FROM CTE1
)
AS StudentTable
PIVOT(MAX(rate)
FOR date IN ('2019-10-08','2019-10-09')
) AS StudentPivotTable;
```

But I am getting an error; "Invalid identifier rate".Please note that no agregation is needed here, since pivot always asks for aggregation, we just gave **MAX()** for sake of completeness. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a CTE instead of that sub-select.  I've used a CTE to explicitly load your values, but you could run that select from CTE1 in an actual CTE:

`WITH x as (
  SELECT $1::date as date_fld, $2 as group_nm, $3 as rate 
  FROM (VALUES
    ('2019-10-08','A',0.43),('2019-10-09','A',0.46),('2019-10-08','B',1.5),('2019-10-09','B',2)
  )
)
SELECT * FROM x
PIVOT(max(rate) for date_fld in ('2019-10-08'::date,'2019-10-09'::date)) as p;`

Also, the documentation examples are very helpful: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/constructs/pivot.html

Comment: May I know what do those dollar signs mean here?Because I am getting only one row in the output.Can you kindly clarify?

Comment: Those are simply positional identifiers for the columns that I'm creating in the VALUES function.  Since you are leveraging a table of data, instead, you'd just directly reference the field names.